Stripe Plugin\Context doesn't exist
Trying to install Stripe on local Magento 2.4 instance
I followed the steps here https://docs.stripe.com/connectors/adobe-commerce/install
But after installing it, Amin page breaks with Plugin class StripeIntegration\Payments\Plugin\Context doesn't exist
I have searched though the local codebase and that class is indeed missing
Only reference is inside stripe/module-payments/etc/frontend/di.xml:
<type name="Magento\Framework\App\Action\AbstractAction">
    <plugin name="stripe_context_currency" type="StripeIntegration\Payments\Plugin\Context" sortOrder="100"/>
</type>

Magento is run from Bitnami Docker Compose file
composer.json has this:
"require": {
    "magento/composer-dependency-version-audit-plugin": "~0.1",
    "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "^2.0.4",
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.7",
    "stripe/stripe-payments": "^4.0"
},


Downgrading stripe/stripe-payments to v3 fixes it for now
